# react-native flatList, make negative space between each element

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, css-in-js

I tried to make a flatlist of image, but each image should be above the others:

[image]

```js
<FlatList
    style={styles.listAvatar}
    data={item.etudiants}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => <ItemAvatar urlAvatar={item.avatar} />}
    horizontal
/>
```

```js
const ItemAvatar = ({urlAvatar}:any) => {
    return (
            <Image
                style={{ width: 35, height: 35, borderRadius: 100}}
                source={{uri: urlAvatar}}
            />
    )
}
```

[image]

So I tried to do something like that:

```js
<Image
    style={{ width: 35, height: 35, borderRadius: 100, marginRight: -15}}
    source={{uri: urlAvatar}}
/>
```

But I got:

[image]

The last image is cut..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```js
<Image
    style={{
      width: 35,
      height: 35,
      borderRadius: 100,
      left: index * -15,
    }}
    source={{ uri: urlAvatar }}
/>
```